# Alexa skill requires two slots to be filled, however even when filling both slots in request, skill still requests them individually

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, alexa-skills-kit

I am building a test alexa skill that will assist with purchasing products. It expects both the name of the product, and the number of units to purchase. These slots have been set up as required to fulfill the intent, and while they can be fulfilled individually, I have set up sample utterances that allow the user to fulfill both in the same sentence, e.g.

```
I want to buy {MyQuantity} {MyArticle}
```

However, in testing, Alexa will always ask for both values individually. Below is a sample of the conversation flow, and below that, the JSON output of my skill. Unsure what I'm doing wrong. (I have delegated the dialog management to Alexa in this case).

[image]

The JSON configuration of the skill:

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "priceline collect",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "CreateOrder",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "MyArticle",
                            "type": "ClickCollectArticle",
                            "samples": [
                                "I want to buy {MyArticle}",
                                "I want {MyArticle}",
                                "Can i get {MyArticle} please",
                                "I'd like to buy {MyArticle}"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MyQuantity",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
                            "samples": [
                                "{MyQuantity} thanks",
                                "I want {MyQuantity} please"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "I want to buy {MyQuantity} {MyArticle}",
                        "I want to buy {MyArticle}",
                        "Can i please get {MyQuantity} {MyArticle}",
                        "I want to order {MyArticle}",
                        "I would like to place an order"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "ClickCollectArticle",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "foundation"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "conditioner"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "shampoo"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "perfume"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "after shave"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "aftershave"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "hairspray"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "hair gel"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "lipstick"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "dialog": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "CreateOrder",
                    "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS",
                    "confirmationRequired": true,
                    "prompts": {
                        "confirmation": "Confirm.Intent.847210063881"
                    },
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "MyArticle",
                            "type": "ClickCollectArticle",
                            "confirmationRequired": true,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "confirmation": "Confirm.Slot.847210063881.746398127202",
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.847210063881.746398127202"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MyQuantity",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
                            "confirmationRequired": true,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "confirmation": "Confirm.Slot.847210063881.631830388134",
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.847210063881.631830388134"
                            },
                            "validations": [
                                {
                                    "type": "isLessThan",
                                    "prompt": "Slot.Validation.369260633406.54462952385.1162755638931",
                                    "value": "20"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
        },
        "prompts": [
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.847210063881.746398127202",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "We sell all kinds of awesome stuff, from lipstick to hairspray. What would you like to buy?"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "We sell everything from shampoo to foundation. What would you like to order?"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "What item would you like to order. Examples are lipstick or foundation. "
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Confirm.Slot.847210063881.746398127202",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Great. So that's {MyArticle} ?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.847210063881.631830388134",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "What number of {MyArticle} would you like to purchase?"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "How many {MyArticle} were you after?"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "And how many of the item {MyArticle} would you like to buy?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Confirm.Slot.847210063881.631830388134",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Awesome. So {MyQuantity} {MyArticle} ?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Confirm.Intent.847210063881",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Ok. It looks like we're all ready to get you {MyQuantity} units of {MyArticle} , is that right?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Slot.Validation.369260633406.54462952385.1162755638931",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Sorry, you can't order that many units. Please order less than twenty. "
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: don't entirely trust the text based simulator to check if the skill behaves correctly or not, also try on a real devices.  You might observe subtle differences between a real device and the simulator, in particular for slot filling.  Secondly, I would suggest to log the full incoming request received by your skill to understand how Alexa Simulator is filling up the slot.  Finally, when using the text based simulator, it is always better to write number in letters (five instead of 5)

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, do you happen to have any useful links for how to get a skill ready to test on a real device? (I have an echo on my desk, but I don't want to publish this skill to the wide world just yet... however I would like to test it on a real device).

Comment: If you are using the same amazon account for dev and to register your device, there is nothing to do. When you can test on the simulator, your skill is also available on the device. You can see your dev skill in the Alexa app on mobile or Alexa.amazon.com